# What is the standard deviation of a gaussian filter?

Tags: standard-deviation, kernel-smoothing

I was referring to this thesis, [High dimensional gaussian filtering for computational photography](http://books.google.com/books?id=ihe0nfm97eIC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) (or [pdf](http://people.csail.mit.edu/abadams/thesis.pdf)), for understanding gaussian filters.

However, I didn't understand one part. The gaussian filter is given by

$$
\hat{v_i} = \sum_{j}\exp(-|p_i-p_j|^2 / 2)\,v_j
$$

If $p_i$ and $p_j$ are position vectors then it is simply the Gaussian blur. Now I didn't understand if we divide $p_i$ and $p_j$ by a certain constant, the standard deviation of the filter is changed. I didn't get how it occurs. Also I didn't get what you mean by the standard deviation of a filter?

Answer (score 2):

This question actually has (next to) nothing to do with "standard deviation" in the sense understood in statistics.  A more precise term for what is being changed is the ["radius"](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/GaussianFilter.html) or "half-width" of the filter.  Whatever it is called--standard deviation, radius, whatever--it always refers to the *typical distance over which the kernel (here, $e^{-|p_i-p_j|^2/2}$) has appreciable magnitude.*

When you uniformly rescale the $p_i$, you are effectively changing the units of distance measurement.  (For instance, dividing 12 feet by 3 converts it to 4 yards.)  It's the same distance but it is expressed with a different number.  But because the numeric value of this distance has changed, the values of the kernel change too.

It helps to know that most kernels (and the Gaussian is typical) attain their highest values at 0 (i.e., when $p_i = p_j$) and decrease from there.  Thus, *decreasing* the numeric value in the kernel's argument (which is never negative) *increases* the kernel's value.  This means that positions that once were so far apart to contribute essentially nothing to the kernel might now start contributing something.  In short, *shrinking* the numbers *increases* the apparent "reach" of the kernel itself: its radius (aka "standard deviation") extends proportionately.

Comment: I have read the first few pages of the dissertation where the Guassian filter is described. While I agree that the Gaussian filter in this case is a spatial smoothing of image data I saw the term "standard deviation" of the filter mentioned, I do not see it formally defined. Perhaps I would need to dig deeper into the paper to see. But the smoothed points are estimates of the pixel intensities in the two-dimensional space and by standard deviation of the filter he could mean the standard deviation of these estimates based on the weights set for the filter.

Comment: In that case my answer would be prefectly correct and your answer misses the mark.  But if I am right the term standard deviation is not really defined in the thesis.

Comment: @whuber I know your reason for closing my answer.  I don't agree with it.  If you think it requires more discussion we can chat.  I prefer not to spend time in chat on this but leave it up to you if you think it is important. What I do want to know is whether or not you agree that the term "variance of the filter" in the dissertation is well defined or not and if not what might be your objection to my answer and do you maintain that yours is correct?

Comment: @Michael Your answer is not closed; it is only locked to prevent misuse of the comments. I agree that the dissertation did not define its terms. As my first comment to your answer states, I do not object to your answer *per se,* but I think that the context established by the dissertation is a different one than assumed by that answer. Finally, your question intimates that something in my answer is not correct. This used to be right, but Cardinal kindly (and silently) fixed an (embarrassing) typographical error with an edit. Is there something else that should be improved?